# Magento quantity issues

Tags: php, magento

When we update attributes of product all simple product quantity 1000 and configure product quantity 0 .Will it possible to recover old quantity

Answer (score 0):

Only if you have a backup of your database previous to the change.

Answer (score 0):

That is updated in Database so you can talk to your hosting company for the backup, many hosting company have this option.